# Not able to see field Design and perform tab in Form builder

Tags: sitecore-forms

Currently using `Sitecore.NET 10.2.0 (rev. 006766)` I am getting issues related to form in the Form builder. Getting below error in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'IsDisabled')
    at Object.loadFormCompleted (FormDesigner.js:304:74)
    at triggerEvents (sitecore.js:1479:43)
    at Object.trigger (sitecore.js:1626:13)
    at Object.loadFormSuccess (FormDesignBoard.js:169:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.1.js:3230:33)
    at fire (jquery-2.1.1.js:3073:30)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.js:3185:7)
    at done (jquery-2.1.1.js:8251:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.1.js:8598:9)
```

Also, a few images in not loading See in the attached screenshot

**Console Error**[image]

What should I do to resolve this error and what should we need check configuration for same issue

Comment: OP: I'm getting the same error. Did you ever find a solution? To people complaining about me posting this as an answer instead of a comment. I can't: You must have 50 reputation to comment

Comment: Does the issue still occur in a private browsing tab? Do the Sitecore logs say anything? Do you have any custom code related to Sitecore Forms? Does it happen on all forms? What if you create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

I tried same thing in `Sitecore.NET 10.2.0 (rev. 006766)` vanilla instance and I am not getting any issue. You can try below approaches.

1. Can you please make sure you have all scripts as shown in below screenshot on the following path `your_Root\sitecore modules\Web\ExperienceForms\scripts`

[image]

2. Comments out custom JS files because they also conflict with OOTB JS files in Sitecore.

Hope this will help you.